# Display an object with Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

I need help to display an object of firebase with angular. I try to display the object [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSFiX.png) with a console.log and the html

```html
<div *ngFor="let k of body | keys ; let i = index">
   <h2>{{ body.nombre }} </h2>
</div>
```

```html
{nombre: "chat1"} 
nombre: "chat1"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Try k.nombre instead of body.nombre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `get`ter that will return to you the keys using `Object.keys(...)`.

In the template you can then loop through the keys and print the value of each key using the `[]` member access operator:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  body = { nombre: 'Chat1', foo: 'bar' };

  get transformedBody() {
    return Object.keys(this.body);
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of transformedBody">
  <h2>{{ key }}: {{ body[key] }}</h2>
</div>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nrsju?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try

```
<div *ngFor="let k of data"> -- where data is the field name to which you are saving the data
    <h2>{{ k.nombre }} </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work. The OP wants to iterate through each item in the Object and print its value.